# How to determine at which point in python script step memory exceeded in SLURM

Tags: python, memory, slurm

I have a `python` script that I am running on a `SLURM` cluster for multiple input files:

```
#!/bin/bash

#SBATCH -p standard
#SBATCH -A overall 
#SBATCH --time=12:00:00
#SBATCH --output=normalize_%A.out
#SBATCH --error=normalize_%A.err
#SBATCH --nodes=1
#SBATCH --ntasks=1
#SBATCH --cpus-per-task=20
#SBATCH --mem=240000

HDF5_DIR=...
OUTPUT_DIR=...
NORM_SCRIPT=...

norm_func () {
  local file=$1
  echo "$file"
  python $NORM_SCRIPT -data $file -path $OUTPUT_DIR
}

# Doing normalization in parallel
for file in $HDF5_DIR/*; do norm_func "$file" & done
wait
```

The python script is just loading a dataset (`scRNAseq`), does its normalization and saves as `.csv` file. Some major lines of code in it are:

```
        f = h5py.File(path_to_file, 'r')
        rawcounts = np.array(rawcounts)

        unique_code = np.unique(split_code)
        for code in unique_code:
            mask = np.equal(split_code, code)
            curr_counts = rawcounts[:,mask]

            # Actual TMM normalization
            mtx_norm = gmn.tmm_normalization(curr_counts)

            # Writing the results into .csv file
            csv_path = path_to_save + "/" + file_name + "_" + str(code) + ".csv"
            with open(csv_path,'w', encoding='utf8') as csvfile:
                writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',')
                writer.writerow(["", cell_ids])
                for idx, row in enumerate(mtx_norm):
                    writer.writerow([gene_symbols[idx], row])
```

I keep getting `step memory exceeded` error for datasets that are above `10Gb` and I am not sure why. How I can change my `.slurm` script or `python` code to reduce its memory usage? How can I actually identify what causes the `memory` problem, is there a particular way of debugging the memory in this case? Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get refined information by using `srun` to start the python scripts:

```
srun python $NORM_SCRIPT -data $file -path $OUTPUT_DIR
```

Slurm will then create one 'step' per instance of your python script, and report information (errors, return codes, memory used, etc.) for each step independently in the accounting, which you can interrogate with the `sacct` command.

If configured by the administrators, use the `--profile` option to get a timeline of the memory usage of each step.

In your python script you can use the [memory_profile](https://pypi.org/project/memory_profiler/) module to get a feedback on the memory usage of your scripts.

Comment: Could we use `@profile` from `memory_profiler` module just before the `if __name__ == '__main__':`? Because all of my code is in there. Also, could you give a brief example of how to use `sacct`? I am not sure about it.

Comment: I isolated several functions from the main method and did profiling, but it fails if there is the `step memory exceeded` error. I want to know how much memory it actually needs in the step that does not go through.

Comment: if you run `sacct -j <JOBID> -o jobid,maxis,state` you will get a 3-column view of all steps in the job with the memory consumed and the final state (completed, error, etc.)