# Reduce memory usage of a line of code that uses numpy

Tags: python, numpy, memory

I am using the `python` library:

https://github.com/ficusss/PyGMNormalize

For normalizing my datasets (`scRNAseq`) and the last line in the library's file `utils.py`:

https://github.com/ficusss/PyGMNormalize/blob/master/pygmnormalize/utils.py

uses too much of memory:

```
np.percentile(matrix[np.any(matrix > 0, axis=1)], p, axis=0)
```

Is there a good way of rewriting this line of code to improve the memory usage? I mean I have `200Gb` `RAM` accessible on the cluster and with the `matrix` of something like `20Gb` this line fails to work, but I beliebve there should be a way of making it working.

Comment: Here's a question I recently answered that had similar problems with (using `np.median`, which uses percentile internally).  Basically you need to take a per-column percentile to keep it from hogging ram, something like "[np.percentile(c, p) for c in cmatrix[np.any(matrix > 0, axis=1)]].T" (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52102181/optimizing-my-large-data-code-with-little-ram)

Comment: Ok, then what is `cmatrix`? Just `matrix.T`? Or just a typo?

Comment: I actually changed the line to `[np.percentile(c, p) for c in matrix[np.any(matrix > 0, axis=1)]].T` but it did not fix the memory issue. Probably it should be improved further.

Comment: Yup, that's a typo.  How are you measuring memory usage?

Comment: I needed to also change it to `np.array([np.percentile(c, p) for c in matrix[np.any(matrix > 0, axis=1)]]).T` since `list` does not have `.T` function. But it is still not working: I am getting the memory error.

Comment: I am working on the cluster. Already asked the question, so trying to follow what is in the answer, but so far no success: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52229942/how-to-determine-at-which-point-in-python-script-step-memory-exceeded-in-slurm

Comment: Pretty much I can not use `memory profiler` because there is `step memory exceeded` error and so it can not be profiled due to the exception. but I know for sure which line of code is doing that. Just need to change it somehow for it to not use so much of the memory.

Comment: are all elements of `matrix >= 0?`

Comment: Ultimately I gave up on using the `PyGMNormalize` after reading another thread on `stackoverflow`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52242004/package-to-perform-tmm-normalization-in-python which says that even matrices generated are not the same as the widely used `R` packages methods. I guess the package needs further work/debugging.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all elements of `matrix` are >=0, then you can do:

```
np.percentile(matrix[np.any(matrix, axis = 1)], p, axis = 0)
```

This uses the fact that any float or integer other than `0` is interpreted as `True` when viewed as a boolean (which `np.any` does internally).  Saves you from building that big boolean matrix seperately.

Since you're boolean indexing in `matrix[...]`, you're creating a temporary copy that you don't really care if it gets overwritten during the `percentile` process.  Thus you can use `overwrite_input = True` to save even more memory.

```
mat = matrix.copy()
perc = np.percentile(matrix[np.any(matrix, axis = 1)], p, axis = 0, overwrite_input = True)
np.array_equals(mat, matrix) # is `matrix` still the same?

True
```

Finally, depending on your other archetecture, I'd recommend looking into making `matrix` some flavor of `scipy.sparse`, which should siginficantly reduce your memory usage again (although with some drawbacks depending on the type you use).

Comment: Good answer, but I'm not sure why you're comparing `mat` and `matrix`.  Even if they compare as true for some inputs it's not guaranteed when using `overwrite_input=True`.

Comment: @user2699 can you show an example where it doesn't work?  I can't find any, and the boolean-indexed slice of `matrix` should be a copy, instead of a view to the original `matrix`. So if it is changed, it shouldn't effect `matrix` itself.

Comment: You're right. Since it's operating on a copy the original won't change, I missed that.

Answer (score 1):

I'm putting this as an answer since there's more than will fit in a comment, although it may not be complete.  There's two suspicious things - first off percentile should run fine on a 20Gb matrix if your machine has 200Gb of ram available.  That's a lot of memory, so start looking into what else might be using it.  Start with `top` - is there another process or is your python program using all of that?

The second suspicious thing is that the documentation for `utils.percentile` doesn't match it's actual behavior.  Here's the relevant bits from the code you've linked to:

```
def percentile(matrix, p):
    """
    Estimation of percentile without zeros.
    ....
    Returns
    -------
    float
        Calculated percentile.
    """
    return np.percentile(matrix[np.any(matrix > 0, axis=1)], p, axis=0)
```

What it actually does is return the (columnwise) percentile calculated for rows which are not all zeros. **edit** That's rows which contain at least one positive element.  If values are non-negative that's the same thing, but in general that will be a very different result.

`np.any(matrix > 0, axis=1)` returns a boolean array to index rows which are not all zeros.  For example

```
>>> np.any(array([[3, 4], [0, 0]]) > 0, axis=1)
    array([ True, False])

>>> np.any(array([[3, 4], [1, 0]]) > 0, axis=1)
    array([ True,  True])

>>> np.any(array([[3, 0], [1, 0]]) > 0, axis=1)
    array([ True,  True])
```

That array is used to index `matrix`, which selects only rows which are not all zeros and returns those.
You should read over [the numpy docs for indexing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html) if you aren't familiar with that way of indexing.

Calculating that takes a lot of memory - `matrix > 0` creates a boolean array of the same dimension as matrix, then the indexing creates a copy of `matrix` which probably contains most of the rows.
So, probably 2-4Gb for the boolean array and close to 20Gb for the copy.

That can be reduced,

```
## Find rows with all zeros, one row at a time to reduce memory
mask = [np.any(r > 0) for r in matrix]  
 ## Find percentile for each column, excluding rows with all zeros
perc = [np.percentile(c[mask], p) for c in matrix.T]
```

However, as stated earlier that doesn't match the function documentation.

There may be a reason for this logic, but it is odd.
If you don't know the reason for it you might be fine calling `np.percentile` directly - just check that it returns a close value for a smaller subset of your data.
There's also `nanpercentile`, which can be used the same way but ignores `nan` values.
You can use boolean indexing to replace the values you don't want included with `nan` (i.e. `matrix[matrix < 0] = np.nan`) and then call that.

Comment: Still can't fix it. The error persists. I tried using `sacct --format="JobID,Elapsed,MaxVMSize`, and it gives the memory `205Gb` for the job.

Comment: Right, so this line probably isn't the one causing memory problems.  It's just the line where things finally fail because some part of the process is hogging memory.  Did you run `top` and what did it show?

Comment: I did but it is the SLURM cluster, and it did not show anything relevant I think