# `np.any` returns an object from an object array instead of boolean?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix

Ok, in trying to answer [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52266003/reduce-memory-usage-of-a-line-of-code-that-uses-numpy/52269841#52269841) I came across something very strange.

```
matrix = np.zeros(10000)
matrix[np.random.choice(10000, 100)] = np.random.rand(100)
matrix = matrix.reshape(10, 1000)

from scipy.sparse import lil_matrix
l = lil_matrix(matrix.T)
l.rows

Out: array([[], [], [], ..., [], [], []], dtype=object)
```

Ok, so I want to know which rows have data, so I tried:

```
np.any(l.rows)

Out: [8]
```

. . . ***what?***

```
out = np.any(l.rows)
type(out)

Out: list
```

It's a list.  With an 8 in it.  Which seems . . . random.  What is going on?

After playing around it seems it returns the first `object` in the array that's not `[]`.

```
np.random.seed(9)
matrix = np.zeros(10000)
matrix[np.random.choice(10000, 100)] = np.random.rand(100)
matrix = matrix.reshape(10, 1000)

from scipy.sparse import lil_matrix
l = lil_matrix(matrix.T)
l.rows

Out: array([[], [], [5], ..., [], [], []], dtype=object)

np.any(l.rows)
Out: [5]
```

But considering `np.any` is only supposed to output `boolean` or `np.array` of boolean, this is a very strange result.  Does anyone know why this happens?

Comment: Addendum: my google-fu is weak, but I can't find any error report for this on github (which it should probably have since indexing by the result will cause some *very* unitntended outcomes).  Not sure how to raise it myself though.

Comment: Isn't `[]` "auto-convertible" to false, and `8` to true? In other words, if you do `if np.any(l.rows):`, does this work "as expected" even though the underlying value is not true/false?

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen Yes, when passed as a boolean they are interpreted as expected.  The problem is in this case if they were used to index, for example `l[np.any(l.rows)]` - granted that's an extremely naive application that I never should have thought would work in the first place.

Comment: No, I meant that if `np.any` returns the first "non-null" element, instead of a bool, is a "non-null" element auto-convertible to "true" if you use it in a boolean context? Meaning: `if np.any(l.rows): x`, will this execute `x` if `np.any(l.rows)` returns `8`?

Comment: Yes, you can test it yourself.

Comment: I don't have Python or numpy installed, my question was more alluding to "is this really a problem at all?"

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen Ahh, sorry.  Forgot the `sparse-matrix` tag would ping some folks from other langauges.  Yes it is a problem if you expect a boolean and use it for boolean indexing.  If the `object` returned can be interpeted by the indexer as some other index than `True` (such as, for example, a list of integers), the resulting slice will point to the wrong location.

Comment: `l.rows` is a object array of lists.  `np.any(x)` does `np.logical_or.reduce(x)`, which apparently for object arrays is evaluated as `x[0] or x[1] or x[2] or x[3] ...`.   Python `or` short circuits returning the first True case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it.  Apparently it's been on the [Easy Fix](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/4352) list since 2014, but finally has [someone working on it](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/pull/11857) since last week.

Should have figured I'm not the first dummy to try something like that.

Also, the correct usage in this case would be:

```
l[l.rows.astype(bool)]
Out: 
<97x10 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 100 stored elements in LInked List format>
```